# Magento 2- secured website but still DNS error

Tags: magento2, error, frontend

i secured my website in the starting so that i can't get any error but its giving me an error:
[image]

everyday. 
even if any new client visit my web it shows the error and then you have to clear the history but after 20-30 minutes it shows the error again.
i'm fed up of this can someone here tell me the permanent solution for this?

Comment: You need to install the SSL from your server.

Comment: i din't get it what you mean can uh kindly explain sir

Comment: i checked and it is already installed on the server